# FLEX - ZXing - Android, Mobile - Barcode Reader

Tags: android, ios, flash, apache-flex, zxing

Based on http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-a-qr-code-reader-in-flex-on-android  and the zxing client sample code, I tried to create an apps which can read any type of code. But on my device, it's working fine while using Qrcode, but doesn't work with any others  type of code, specially Barcode; Where i'm wrong? Here is the code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Scanner">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.BitmapAsset;
            import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
            import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
            import com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap;
            import com.google.zxing.BufferedImageLuminanceSource;
            import com.google.zxing.DecodeHintType;
            import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader;
            import com.google.zxing.Result;
            import com.google.zxing.client.result.ParsedResult;
            import com.google.zxing.client.result.ResultParser;
            import com.google.zxing.common.GlobalHistogramBinarizer;
            import com.google.zxing.common.flexdatatypes.HashTable;
            //import com.google.zxing.oned.EAN13Reader;
            //import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeReader;

            import flashx.textLayout.tlf_internal;

            protected var camera:Camera;
            private var videoDisplay:Video = new Video(300, 300);
            private var myReader:MultiFormatReader;
            private var bmd:BitmapData;
            private var cameraStarted:Boolean = false;


            protected function start_camera(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                myReader = new MultiFormatReader();

                if(!cameraStarted){
                    if(Camera.isSupported) {
                        camera = Camera.getCamera();
                        camera.setMode(300, 300, 15);

                        videoDisplay.x = 295;
                        sv.addChild(videoDisplay);

                        videoDisplay.attachCamera(camera);
                        videoDisplay.rotation = 90;

                        btn.label = "Scan Now";
                        lbl.text = "";
                        cameraStarted = true;
                    } else {
                        lbl.text = "No camera found";
                    }
                } else {
                    decodeSnapshot();
                }
            }

            public function decodeSnapshot():void {
                lbl.text = "Checking...";
                bmd = new BitmapData(300, 300);
                bmd.draw(videoDisplay, null, null, null, null, true);
                videoDisplay.cacheAsBitmap = true;
                videoDisplay.cacheAsBitmapMatrix = new Matrix;
                decodeBitmapData(bmd, 300, 300);
                bmd.dispose();
                bmd=null;
                System.gc();
            }

            public function decodeBitmapData(bmpd:BitmapData, width:int, height:int):void {
                var lsource:BufferedImageLuminanceSource = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bmpd);
                var bitmap:BinaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(lsource));

                var ht:HashTable = null;
                ht = this.getAllHints();

                var res:Result = null;
                try {
                    res = myReader.decode(bitmap, ht);
                } 

                catch (event:Error) {

                }

                if (res == null) {
                    videoDisplay.clear();
                    lbl.text = "Nothing decoded";
                } else {
                    var parsedResult:ParsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(res);
                    lbl.text = parsedResult.getDisplayResult();
                    sv.removeChild(videoDisplay);
                    cameraStarted = false;
                    btn.label = "Start Camera";
                }

            }

            private function getAllHints():HashTable {
                var ht:HashTable = new HashTable;
                //ht.Add(DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS, BarcodeFormat.EAN_13);
                return ht;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VGroup height="100%" width="100%" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" left="0" horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="300" horizontalAlign="center" id="vg">
            <s:SpriteVisualElement id="sv" width="300" height="200" />
        </s:VGroup>
        <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center" >
            <s:Button id="btn" width="220" height="36" label="Start Camera"
                      click="start_camera(event)"/>
            <s:Label id="lbl" x="106" y="291" text=""/>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:View>
```

Comment: I have the same problem... have you solved it???

Answer (score 1):

Your `camera.setMode(300, 300, 15);` is wrong, use:

```
this.camera.setMode( 320, 240, 15, true );
```

Remember that the detection with the AS3 version is not as strong like the native Android code of zxing.

**Edit:** 
Reading your post wrong, you have to add a hash for the format you want and push it into the hash array.